# Entering EU after deportation from US

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, eu, deportation

I was deported from the USA for over staying my visa. I am still under the entry ban period. Recently while backpacking through central america, I was turned away from entering Mexico because of my US deportation. I was flagged as attempting to enter the US through Mexico.

Needless to say I was caught off guard by this, but it appears to be a reasonable policy. Is there any such restriction for traveling to Western Europe? My country of origin (AR) allows for visa free travel to most EU countries. I can't imagine there is, but the consequences of finding out only when I get there are much greater than what I experienced in Mexico.

Answer (score 6):

If you by 'Western Europe' and 'EU' mean Schengen countries, then your deportation from the US should, at least in theory, not matter. Your eligibility to enter the Schengen area should (and hopefully will) be verified based on the credentials you currently present when trying to enter.

If you have a deportation stamp in your passport and the immigration officer notices, you might expect more scrutiny and a more thorough examination. If your passport does not contain any traces of the US deportation, the Schengen immigration officer is not likely to have this information from any other sources.